# Cloning once after getting value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/NgEpS/1/ basically, I am getting the value of a textarea on each form and the appending the value to a child div, everything works.perfect after the first submit, but if you submit more than once the same form, my script is cloning all the previous replies, wondering if there is any way to avoid this.

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="post-container">
            <form class="reply-form">
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <textarea placeholder="Reply box 1..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
                <div class="post-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">1</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="post-container">
            <form class="reply-form">
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <textarea placeholder="Reply box 2..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
                <div class="post-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply hidden"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="post-container">
            <form class="reply-form">
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <textarea placeholder="Reply box 3..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
                <div class="post-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">1</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">2</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">3</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">4</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        p​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
        function gettingReplyVal() {

            $('.reply-form').submit(function(e) {
                var post_clone =    $('.post-dropdown-content').first().clone();

                var textAreaValue = $(this).find('textarea').val();

                 $(post_clone).insertBefore($(this).f ind(".post-dropdown-content")).find('.post-dropdown-reply').html(textAreaValue); 

                e.preventDefault();

            });
        }

        gettingReplyVal();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
$(post_clone).insertBefore($(this).find(".post-dropdown-content")).find('.post-dropdown-reply').html(textAreaValue);
```

`$(this).find(".post-dropdown-content")` returns all the post-dropdown-content elements inside `this`. The first time you hit send, there is only one, so it behaves normally, but the second time it finds two, the third time it finds three, etc...

use `$(this).find(".post-dropdown-content").first()` instead

```
$(post_clone).insertBefore($(this).find(".post-dropdown-content").first()).find('.post-dropdown-reply').html(textAreaValue);
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgEpS/2/) for testing. Does that behave the way you expect it to?